# framework play 2.2.1 Jboss

Tags: deployment, jboss, playframework, ejb

I can't deploy a play application framework 2.2.1 in JBoss.

I must do an application that communicates with EJBs and deploy into the same application server JBOSS.
the only way I have found is to use the start command.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the play war plugin, that will allow you to package your play app as a regular java web archive.

You can find the project here: https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin